# PSR-4 autoloader Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have my project structure like so:

```
src/
   ├─ Model/
      └─ User.php
```

My User.php file looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace Bix\Model;
    
class User {
```

And my composer.json autoloader is this:

```json
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
     "Bix\\": "src/"
   }
}
```

Finally my bootstrap.php is this:

```php
use Bix\Model\User;
    
// PSR-4 Autoloader.
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

However if I try and create a `new User()`, I get the error `Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in /var/www/public/api/v1/index.php on line 8`

Looking at the composer autoload_psr4.php file it looks ok:

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

```php
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname(dirname($vendorDir));
    
return array(
    'XdgBaseDir\\' => array($vendorDir . '/dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir/src'),
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
    'KeenIO\\' => array($vendorDir . '/keen-io/keen-io/src'),
    'Bix\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
);
```

Can anybody point out where I am going wrong with the above?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First of all, Linux (I'm not sure which PC you use) is case-sensitive. In your autoloading, you defined `src/bix`, while it is `src/Bix`.

But more importantly, with PSR-4, the specified namespace prefix is *not* included in the directory structure (to avoid directories containing just one directory). In your case, if you configure `"Bix\\": "src/"`, a class `Bix\Model\User` should be located in `src/Model/User.php`.

---

**EDIT**: You're misunderstanding PHP namespaces. In PHP, you're not saying "import everything from `Bix\Model` into the global namespace for this file" with `use Bix\Model;`. Instead, it means: "Alias `Model` in this file to `Bix\Model`".

So you should either do:

```php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Bix\Model;

$user = new Model\User();
```

or:

```php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Bix\Model\User;

$user = new User();
```

Comment: I updated the composer.json to this: "Bix\\": "src/" and the folder structure to this: src/Model/User.php however there I still get the error 'class User not found'

Comment: @JeremyKirkham after you update autoload configuration, you have to run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader

Comment: I have done this already. I updated my question with the new folder/structure autoloader.

Comment: Going with either of your suggestions still doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my question to use your second method.

Comment: @JeremyKirkham you're doing `new User()` in `bootstrap.php`?

Comment: Yes -- I'm now getting this 'fatal error: Class 'Bix\Model\User' not found'

Comment: All figured -- my src/ folder is actually in public/src, all I needed to do was update my composer.json to "Bix\\": "public/src/" and it worked like a charm. Thanks very much for helping me understand psr-4!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also adding that if you are looking to autoload the current directory you can do this: ``"Foo\\": ""`` without including any slashes.