# issues when autoloading files with psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I've been trying to get psr-4 autoloading work for over a week now with no success.

My file structure is as follows:

```
-Project
  -src
    -classes
       session.php
  -vendor
  index.php
```

I've created the psr-4 autoload function as follows:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
         "classes\\": "src/classes"
    }

}
```

after using composer dump-autoload -0 ,inside my session.php class I gave the namespace:

```
namespace classes;

class session{

public static function exist($name){

    return(isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}
```

I then required the autoloader and used the use function to name the session class as follows:

```
use src\classes\session as session;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

session::put('test', 'test');
```

after opening up the index.php page, I get a

> Fatal error: Class 'src\classes\session' not found in /var/www/test/Project/index.php on line 10

is my directory structure / php correct? I've tried many different guides online and can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most simple solution:

```
use classes\session;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

session::put('test', 'test');
```

## Unrelated

However, you probably don't want to use `classes` as a vendor namespace, but instead adjust a few things here and there:

### Directory structure

```
-Project
  -src
    Session.php
  -public
    index.php
  -vendor
```

### Autoloading configuration in `composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Juakali\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `Juakali` with a vendor namespace you prefer, this is just a suggestion. Ideally, if you intend to publish your package, it should be one that isn't already claimed by someone else, see https://packagist.org.

For reference, see

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

### `Juakali\Session`

Use the aforementioned vendor namespace of your choice:

```
namespace Juakali;

class Session
{
    public static function exist($name)
    {
        return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }
}
```

Consider using a widely used coding style, for example PSR-2.

For reference, see

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

### `index.php`

Assuming that you want to expose `index.php` as the entry point for a web application, move it into a directory which you feel confident to expose as a document root of your web server, adjust the import in `index.php`, as well as the path to `vendor/autoload.php`:

```
use Juakali\Session;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

Session::put('test', 'test');
```

Comment: After edit - this answer is more thorough than mine, good stuff localheinz

Comment: thanks alot for the help. If i was going to use dependencies such as phpmailer from a class in the src folder, would i still need to use the use\vendor\phpmailer.. etc or do i just include the vendor autoloader?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defining your alias of "src/classes" as 'classes'.
So you need to use:

```
use classes\session;
```

Instead

More info:
[PSR-4 autoloader Fatal error: Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136773/psr-4-autoloader-fatal-error-class-not-found)